# API Gateway's response mapping when my lambda function returns an object

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

Let's say that I have a lambda function that returns an **object** (the word "object" is the keyword here):

```js
module.exports = {
    handler: async (event, context, callback) => {
        const rnd = Math.random();
        if (rnd > 0.33) {
            //Successfull response
            callback(null, { att: "value" });
        }
        else if (rnd > 0.66) {
            //Error response
            const err = new Error("Error message");
            err.name = "ITEM_NOT_FOUND";
            //TODO: return the err object (somehow)
        }
        else {
            //Error response
            const err = new Error("Error message");
            err.name = "GENERIC_ERROR_CODE";
            //TODO: return the err object (somehow)
        }
    }
}
```

And then, I want to integrate this lambda function into an API Gateway entry. For that, I'll need to have at least two "Integration Response" mapping the return object into an HTTP status code (200, 400, ...) through a regex matching.

What I want is that when my lambda function fails (returns an error object), API Gateway should respond back with a **404** HTTP status code if the error code is `ITEM_NOT_FOUND` and **400** otherwise. Of course, if the lambda function does not fail, the HTTP status code should be **200**.

Not to waste your time, I know that I can return my error object like this:

```js
context.fail(JSON.stringify({code: "ITEM_NOT_FOUND", message: "Error message"}));
```

And then the lambda function will return something like this:

```json
{
  "errorType": "string",
  "errorMessage": "{\"code\":\"ITEM_NOT_FOUND\",\"messaage\":\"Error message\"}",
  "trace": []
}
```

But this is not what I'm after since if I call this lambda function using AWS SDK, when I catch the error message, I'll have to parse the error `errorMessage` to get the actual error object. I was hoping there's a way to avoid that while at the same time be able to come up with the API Gateway mapping to detect the error and return the appropriate status code.

Comment: Did you try `callback(err);` instead?

Comment: Yes, I have. Using `callback(err)` has an issue with the API Gateway mapping. The regex in the "Response Integration" won't be able to match any part of the returned value since it is an object.

Comment: Hmm, let's consider using Proxy integration instead.

Comment: @hoangdv Sorry but that's unacceptable by my standard. No lambda function should be tied to HTTP protocol.